1950s or 60s movie; Woman wants a car that is "Pink with blue clouds"
It's already a long time ago but somebody answered "Pink with blue clouds" to a question regarding a paintjob and that reminded me of a line in an old movie from the 50s or 60s.
I don't know if the exact line is "Pink with blue clouds" because I saw that film with German dubs where it said "rosa mit blauen Wölkchen". The car was, as far as I remember, a convertible. I can't even say if it was filmed in color because our TV was B&W (Yes, it was a looong time ago, about 40 years ). The situation of the scene was: woman wants car, man asks for a color and womans answered with the line above. I think the man stole the car.
The actors looked typically like Hollywood made them look in that time but I cannot say it was from the USA for sure. Scenery was a small coastal city, I would say Mediterranean. It was in a hilly terrain, the sort of villages you'll find in northern Italy facing the Ligurian sea, e.g.: when you drive down the SS1 between Savona and Menton. 

Not: Ride in a Pink Car

What country was it likely from? Do you remember the actors or what they looked like? The genre? Any other scenes or plot details?

It's about 40 years since! ;-) Well, the actors looked typically like Hollywood made them look in that time but I cannot say USA for sure. Scenery was a small coastal city, I would say mediteranean. It was in a hilly terrain, the sort of villages you'll find in northern Italy facing the Ligurian sea, e.g.: when you drive down the SS1 between Savona and Menton. Sorry, but I have only that one scene about the car clearly in my memories, the rest is quite foggy.

@Walt  Yes, as I already said, it was a German dub (they are always lipsync) and I vaguely remember the line "rosa mit blauen Wölkchen". "Wölckchen" is the diminutive of "Wolke" cloud, so it could also be a "blue puff" or something in the line. But the paintjob of the car was definitly something with little clouds spread all over.

I just wonder if some details are a bit off. See, there's this scene in the French action farce L'homme de Rio from 1964 with Jean-Paul Belmondo where his demanding girlfriend says they'll need to steal a car. He sarcastically replies, "Oh, a pink one with green stars?"... and in the next scene, they're indeed driving one. In a scenery like you've described (it was filmed in Italy). You can actually see the scene here on Youtube (the relevant bit starts around 0:30).

@Walt you might take the chance to make a proper answer out of it ;-)

No problem. I just wasn't sure enough, but if you want, I'll put it up.

I can't spend my 100 bucks, pardon, points otherwise

This might very well be the 1964 French adventure comedy L'homme de Rio (That Man from Rio) starring Jean-Paul Belmondo. Some details are a bit off, but as you said, it's been 40 years. The plot:

Swarthy thieves ignore jewels to steal an Amazon figurine from the Museum of Man in Paris' Trocadero Palace and kidnap the world's authority on the lost Maltec civilization. Cut to Agnes, the daughter of a murdered man who possessed one of two other such figurines. Moments after her sweetheart, Adrien, an Army private with a week's leave, arrives in Paris to see her, Agnes too is kidnapped, drugged, and loaded on a plane to Rio. Adrien is in hot pursuit, and before he can rescue her (with the help of a shoeshine boy), foil the murderous thieves, and solve the riddle of the Maltecs, he must traverse Rio, Brasília, and the Amazon heartland... all before the end of his week's leave. 

In the relevant scene, Adrien and Agnes need a car, and the dialogue goes something like this:

Agnes: We'll need a car.
Boy: But what color?
Agnes: Yes, what color?
Adrien [sarcastically, since she often has fanciful demands]: A pink one with green stars?

Cut to them driving an ancient, pink Chrysler convertible (that he probably stole) with green stars on it. The scenery is pretty much as you've described (I think it's supposed to be Rio but was filmed in Italy). Here's the scene (the relevant bit is around 0:30):




Yes, that was it! How could I forget it was Belmondo? But,, ok, 40 years are a really long time ;-) Thanks a lot! (bounty allowed after 6 hour waiting period, says stackexchange, so please be patient)

My pleasure. And that's OK, remembering Belmondo might not have narrowed it down that much; I think he was in every single French film in the 60s. ;)

Not in every but in 18, according to wikipedia. A bit too much, even for a very long weekend ;-)
